# How do I filter the models I see in the Add View dialog window with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models

Is there a way to restrict what I see when I select the View Data Class drop down, to just the models in my Application?  It seems that if I have any references in my app, that drop down gets really noisy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start typing in the box, it will start doing autocomplete and get you closer to the class of interest.  Not really a solution, but it is helpful.

Comment: This works but there needs to be a better permanent solution to this... there is no reason to show classes from some of the referenced libraries in this list.